# How can I exclude all files in META-INF except for the three signature files?

Tags: android, apk

I had the understanding that Android apk files contain the app and a signature in the META-INF folder where the META-INF folder doesn't contain any executable (runtime relevant?) stuff but my gradle build throws numerous files there that I think are not needed. I can exclude those from the META-INF folder but not those from the META-INF/services folder. Why is that?

I had to deal with:

```
$ apksigner verify --print-certs --verbose  ~/Downloads/release_mbw/comp_3.8.9.0_forRelease_docker/mbw-prodnet-release.apk 
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=Mycelium Developers, O=Mycelium, L=Vienna, C=AT
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: b8e59d4a60b65290efb2716319e50b94e298d7a72c76c2119eb7d8d3afac302e
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: be575ec3b3b52e0b2392146cbdb245c91ef5a04f
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: 7aec063675b0206aba3b6175b89abc7d
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: 6d9c0cda9dcd3ec5efcdca41243829b1dcf1e9a91c6309bca167807282590a20
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: b34336038c7ca678285c14aebe78b7d5add90e4c
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: a78bdb2b6d074db4b1ff12eb9cddcfa3
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-fragment.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-dynamic-features-fragment.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.room_room-runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidfioserializationprovider_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-coroutines.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/metadata.jvm.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/org.ocpsoft.prettytime.PrettyTime not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-v4.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/navigation-runtime-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/navigation-fragment-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/retrofit.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.ExternalOverridabilityCondition not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/navigation-dynamic-features-runtime_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-runtime-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.media_media.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.savedstate_savedstate.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.core_core.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable-animated.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-common-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/sqldelight-sqlite-driver.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoader not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/descriptors.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/sqldelight-rxjava2-extensions.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata-core.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/sqldelight-runtime.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/rxkotlin.properties not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.print_print.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/wapi.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.core_core-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-fragment-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/walletcore.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-reactivestreams.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.arch.core_core-runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/type-system.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.activity_activity.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/lifecycle-runtime-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/descriptors.runtime.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/deserialization.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.databinding_viewbinding.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/sqldelight-android-driver_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/bitlib.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-viewmodel.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/navigation-ui-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-service.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-ui-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.sqlite_sqlite.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.google.android.material_material.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.activity_activity-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-extensions.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/rxkotlin_main.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/activity-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-dynamic-features-runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.firebase.firebase_analytics_ktx_granule.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.preference_preference.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-ui.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.databinding_library.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/fragment-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat-resources.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/util.runtime.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/modularization-lib_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/fiosdk.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.sqlite_sqlite-framework.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/collection-ktx.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.google.firebase-firebase-common-ktx.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/metadata.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/view_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/mbw_prodnetRelease.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.navigation_navigation-common.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/navigation-dynamic-features-fragment_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.

...

WARNING: META-INF/com.google.firebase-firebase-dynamic-links-ktx.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/navigation-common-ktx_release.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.cardview_cardview.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/jackson-module-kotlin.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common-coroutines.kotlin_module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
```

added this to my build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/*_module'
        exclude 'META-INF/services'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/*'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/*.*'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/**'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver'
    }
}
```

but now still get:

```
$ apksigner verify --print-certs --verbose  android-wallet/mbw/build/outputs/apk/btctestnet/release/mbw-btctestnet-release.apk 
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=mycelium, OU=android, O=mycelium
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: 833df9af46ea76a857320b9573c511dbe4116dba0914a82bfc5cc428ee4ea16f
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: f410a6121501f3b8e8bdd1ad803ec99efef5b9de
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: 8ac65b251781ad4277d76f67745b3e5a
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: cd26b57f5421259b135b78866439300fbc6312c46268a705981f1c7b1faeee81
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: 440a43e67d364aae0b0dcd4ef584acc486056347
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: bab428a18aee0b1974adc263a54b2fa3
WARNING: META-INF/services/org.ocpsoft.prettytime.PrettyTime not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.ExternalOverridabilityCondition not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoader not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/java.security.Provider not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
```

Neither the blanket exclude META-INF/services/** nor the specific exclude META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver worked.

- Why does gradle add those files?
- Do I need them after all?
- Where is the `exclude META-INF/**; include META-INF/{CERT.{RSA,SF},MANIFEST.MF}` option to not always have to update this section?

Apparently [others observed this issue, too](https://github.com/nextcloud/android/issues/1569#issuecomment-354725484) and yet others use a merge directive on the services folder which doesn't fix my issue neither.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately so far no.

Comment: You can remove those files from the unsigned APK and zipalign+sign the APK yourself.